# Spree Commerce Image (Asset) Associated with multiple OptionValues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm wondering what the best practice is for setting up a relationship as follows.

Currently, Spree offers the following models and associations.

**asset.rb**

```
module Spree
  class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :viewable, polymorphic: true, touch: true
    acts_as_list scope: :viewable
    // ....
  end
end
```

**image.rb** (perhaps this is irrelevant, but inherits from asset model)

```
module Spree
  class Image < Asset
    // .......
  end
end
```

**variant.rb**

```
module Spree
  class Variant < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :option_values, join_table: :spree_option_values_variants, class_name: "Spree::OptionValue"
    has_many :images, -> { order(:position) }, as: :viewable, dependent: :destroy, class_name: "Spree::Image"
    // ......
  end
end
```

**option_value.rb**

```
module Spree
  class OptionValue < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :option_type, :touch => true
    acts_as_list scope: :option_type
    has_and_belongs_to_many :variants, join_table: 'spree_option_values_variants', class_name: "Spree::Variant"
    // ......
  end
end
```

Currently, when an image (asset) is added to a product variant, a single db row is added to the **spree_assets** table. This is desired. Within the spree_assets table is a column called **viewable** which holds the id of the variant. This isn't extremely flexible. Basically, this means that a single image can only be applied to a single variant. Currently the Spree Admin reflects this as well. When uploading a product image, a select box is provided to select a single variant to apply this image to. This could be fine for many stores, but for our store, a **Green T-Shirt** image should apply to Small, Medium, and Large Green T-Shirts.

**Proposed Solution**

I have detailed the proposed solution in a [Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1q2Xke3BoSxVMKPfVTtvhpVkTa-lpWtdyFfSizCPcg5s/edit?usp=sharing).

Basically, I'm thinking a new table should be used. This new table would hold foreign keys for the **asset**, **option_value**, and **variant**. This could certainly be completely wrong, but that's why I'm posting here. :)

Should I create this new db table? Or, are the relationships currently in place to accommodate my needs?

If I do create a new db table, would I need a join model? What should it look like?

This may be too abstract for Stack Overflow, and if so, I apologize. Please PM me if you'd simply like me to hire you to carry out the implementation.

Comment: This kind of question is probably better asked on the Spree mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=de#!forum/spree-user

Comment: That's where I stared, but didn't get far. For now, I've hired a Rails Developer for help. Will open source the implementation when closer to completion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up hiring out some help on this one. For those who are interested, please see the extension here: https://github.com/jpdesigndev/spree_asset_variant_options

Comment: As I try to use the gem for this extension I need to insert a github username and password. Any hints about it ?

Comment: I have no clue. That is not something required of the gem. That's likely due to how you're installing it. It's been years since I've dealt with this gem (Ruby at all for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

In the admin/products//images page

You can upload a 'cover' image  (the same image) for each of the variants Green small, green medium and green large. You also need an 'all' image for the categories page

If all you have for that product is just the green color, then just pick the master image 'all'

**In both cases:**

*Make sure* you've got a/the color selected in the 'Default Colors' section(admin/products_taxons) within the taxonomies the product is under.

Comment: Thanks Uri Mikhli. Unfortunately, the problem I described isn't quite that simple. For anyone who's interested, see the extension I created here: https://github.com/jpdesigndev/spree_asset_variant_options